# Image would not like to open in IE10 and Mozilla

Tags: html, image, cross-browser, browser

I upload image to server and try to load it in different browsers.

I'm using this type of code:

```
<img alt="Name2.jpg" src="http://www.website.net/addVid/maker/Name2.jpg">
```

This is result:

**Chrome**: Working fine.
**Opera**: Working fine.
**IE10**: square with cross.
**Mozilla**: says " The image blablabla.....cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

I have NO idea why it's happens.. any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a live link? If so, please add it so we can test.

Comment: "The image blablabla.....cannot be displayed because it contains errors" - maybe the image hasn't been created properly? try re-making the image, or running it through something to check if the image is correct?

Comment: Yes, image was bad... remove this topic..

Answer (score 0):

URL provided in src is not valid

src="http://pcplacements.com/wp-content/uploads/Hello-Picture.gif"

once try this.

Comment: yours is working...YOUR pictures, but WHY my picture open in chrome and not working in IE?

Answer (score 0):

The link that you provided is invalid however I am assuming that you did not want to post the actual URL for whatever reason.

Why are you trying to load the image via URL, just import the image over to your server and then access it:

```
<img alt="Name2.jpg" src="FileDirectory/Name2.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is with the image. the image only contains the error, once replace the image and try again, i am sure it will.

Definitely.